# Using comparable in a method in the main method

Tags: java, comparable

I am trying to check the values of a comparable method and assign the 1 and -1 value to true and false.  I made a simple if else statement that does just that but I want to make it inside of a method so I can use it multiple times in my main method. When I try to do this I get an error that my compareTo method (in another class) is "undefined for the type Object".

Here is my code for both the compareTo method and my attempt of using this in my test class.

```
public int compareTo(FPNumber o) {
    if ((exp == o.exp) && (fraction - o.fraction < SMALL))
        return 1;
    else if ((exp == o.exp) || (fraction - o.fraction > SMALL))
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

```
public String compare(Object FP1, Object FP2) {
    if (FP1.compareTo(FP2) == 1)
        System.out.println("true");
    else if (FP1.compareTo(FP2) == -1)
        System.out.println("false");
    else
        System.out.println("error");
}
```

Comment: I probably should say that the error is on the compareTo part of FP1.compareTo(FP2) in the second method

Comment: What you are doing is sort of confusing.

Comment: should I post my entire code?

Comment: Yes. This lacks detail.

Comment: Your `compareTo()` method doesn't make sense. The first test should deliver 0, not 1.

Comment: Why does your compare method print "true", "false",  or "error"?  A 'compareTo' method is intended to indicate one value is less than, equal to, or greater than the other.

Comment: @James the method that returns a `String` is a simple wrapper to `compareTo`. There is nothing really wrong with wrapping a method in this manner. Although, in this case, the implementation was a little poor.

Comment: @user207421 that's why I commented that what the OP was doing was confusing.

Comment: @uhhsoup did you read my answer? Are you clear now about what you need to do in your `FPNumber` class?

Comment: @hfontanez Yes. But, returning "error" for zero implies somewhere two FPNumber objects are constrained against having the same value. I have to wonder if that is what the O/P intended.

Comment: @James agreed. This is why I clarified that wrapping the method is OK, but the implementation (of the logic) was poor.

Comment: @uhhsoup, the O/P, didn't actually ask a question. I assumed O/P mainly wanted to know why the error "undefined for the type Object" error was appearing.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by a simple example using raw values, and then expand it to use objects.

Suppose you have two variables `x` and `y` that hold integer values. If I ask you, how do you know if the values for these variables are equal? The question is answered by simple math: if the values of the two variables are equal, the difference between the two must be zero. For example, 5 - 5. In this case, the difference is zero because both variables hold the value of positive 5.

What if they are different? Let `x = 5` and `y = 13`.

1. x - y = -8 (this means that `x < y`)
2. y - x =  8 (same as above)

As you can see, when the values are different, it is not always going to be 1 or -1. This is important when you are comparing more than two values. Let's introduce `z = 20`. If comparing `x` to `y` and `x` to `z` and the result was -1 on both comparisons, the implication is that `y` and `z` must be equal but they are not.

What about when comparing objects? It is the same principle. Even when an object holds multiple variables, you must decide a hierarchy to determine which variable is more or less important in the comparison. Consider the following example

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    ...
    public int compareTo(Person other) {...}
}
```

I can decide that, for my system, when comparing two `Person` objects, I must check first the last name, then the first name, and lastly the age.

```
public int compareTo(Person other) {
    int i = lastName.compareTo(other.lastName);
    if (i != 0) return i;

    i = firstName.compareTo(other.firstName);
    if (i != 0) return i;

    return Integer.compare(age, other.age);
}
```

Basically, if the last names are the same (`i == 0`), it will compare the first names. Then if the first names are the same, it will compare the ages. At any point, if the values are different, the difference will be returned. Again, not a 1 or -1. So basically, to convert the results to boolean, the logic is

```
public boolean compare(Person person, Person other) {
    if (person.compareTo(other) == 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

By the way, your original code has a compilation error because your `compare` method should return a `String` and it returns `void`. Instead of using `System.out.print()` inside your method, like you have now, you should print out the output of the method.

```
public String compare(Object FP1, Object FP2) {
        if (FP1.compareTo(FP2) == 1)
            return "true";
        else if (FP1.compareTo(FP2) == -1)
            return "false";
        else
            return "error";
}

...

System.out.println(compare(FP1, FP2));
```

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention before that, essentially, the `compare` function I included here is serving basically the same function as the `equals()` method. Also, because this function is provided by a third party, it is sort of what a `Comparator` should do. Because of that, it should be done following best practices of what a `Comparator` should do. For my `Person` comparator, you may have two `Comparators`: one that compares age and one that compare names.